# regex for if word is not empty, must be followed

Tags: regex

What is the regex to match the following strings:

```
base.string
a.base.string
b.base.string
cde.base.string
```

This should not match:

```
a.b.c.d.base.string
abase.string
bbase.string
cdebase.string
.base.string
```

I want to match and capture a, b, cde, and the empty string from "base.string"

(a, b, cde are used as example. what can come before base.string is empty string, or any non-empty string followed by a dot.)

Comment: What about `a.b.c.d.base.string` ?

Comment: a.b.c.d.base.string should not batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to match and capture a, b, cde, and the empty string from "base.string"*

Try this :

```
^(?:(?:a|b|cde)\.)?base\.string$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ0fS6/1)

### Generic regex

```
^(?:([^.]+)[.])?base\.string$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: a, b, cde are used as example.  what comes before base.string is empty string, or any non-empty string followed by a dot.

Comment: @bob In this case either M42 or anubhava 's answers should be choosed as correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:([^.]+)\.)?base\.string$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hQ2bT8/3)

Comment: How do I exclude this from matching: cdebase.string

Comment: You can use a negative lookahead for that using: **`^(?!cdebase\.string)([^.]*)\.?base\.string$`**

Comment: Although generic, the regex here will match also the forbidden case stated by OP.

Comment: @Stephan: It is edited now but please pay attention to the fact that I posted my answer before recent edits were made in question that changed the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude `.base.string`, use:

```
^(?:[^.]+\.)?base\.string$
```

Comment: I think this is correct, add braces to capture ^((?:[^.]+\.)?)base\.string$